# Set language in recaptcha - flask

Tags: python, flask, recaptcha, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I am trying to change the error message when the user forget to check the recaptcha checkbox. Even after set the language to pt, I am still receiving this message: `The response parameter is missing.`

```
from flask.ext.wtf import Form, RecaptchaField

recaptcha = RecaptchaField()
```

---

```
RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY = 'yyyy'
RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY = 'xxxx'
RECAPTCHA_PARAMETERS = {'hl': 'pt'}
```

-Language code from [here](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/language)

-Flask [docs1](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-WTF/form.html#recaptcha) [docs2](http://flask-wtf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/form.html#recaptcha) about recpacha

How can i change the language of these messages?

EDIT: Even after the upgrade to the last version of flask-wtforms, the error messages still are always in English. Only the labels change.

Relevant [source code](https://github.com/lepture/flask-wtf/blob/8879e9827b0160776031bd06ef083b81282904e5/flask_wtf/recaptcha/validators.py)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's possible with their current implementation:

https://github.com/lepture/flask-wtf/blob/8879e9827b0160776031bd06ef083b81282904e5/flask_wtf/recaptcha/widgets.py#L8

They have hardcoded URL to the library:
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js

But for different language settings there should be GET parameter passed in the recaptcha URL, for example:
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=ru

I've had to overwrite the field and validation manually for using different language settings.